# Quick Look on OS X 10.9 not showing title, artist and album mp3 tags anymore

Tags: macos, mp3, id3, quicklook

QL on Mavericks appears not to be displaying ID3 tags anymore, only duration time and the illustration of mp3 files. It used to display more before :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOswp.png

Here is the version information of the plugin /System/Library/QuickLook/Audio.qlgenerator which is involved :

```
<key>BuildAliasOf</key>
<string>QuickLook</string>
<key>BuildVersion</key>
<string>2</string>
<key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
<string>5.0</string>
<key>CFBundleVersion</key>
<string>622.7</string>
<key>ProjectName</key>
<string>QuickLookPlugins_generators</string>
<key>SourceVersion</key>
<string>622007000000000</string>
```

PS : I already tried fixing QL following this : http://www.cnet.com/news/fixing-quick-look-issues-in-os-x/ ; nothing's changed.

Could anybody send me a plugin version from a prior OS X version that displays correctly the ID3 tags please ?

-hymced

Comment: Seems to work fine for me on 10.9.4. This question is off topic here, it is better suited to http://superuser.com/ or http://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: OK you are right, but would you mind sharing the version information please, to see if everything is OK ?

Comment: Version info is exactly the same as yours.

Comment: ok  thanks, I've just tried replacing it with the version of OS X Lion, no change either, so me guess is that the problem isn't from the plugin itself... Perian is installed, I have no idea why it does that. Plus, I have an almost fresh install.

Comment: To every idiots on earth : NOT A GOOD IDEA TO OVERWRITE QuickLook.framework WITH ON OLDER VERSION ! Finder crashes and cannot reload properly, but hopefully I had saved the original framework and could cp it booting from my USB stick installer. Initial problem still unresolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[qlBitRate](https://github.com/jordansaints/qlBitRate/releases/) is your friend. To install, download the latest zip, unzip it and drop `qlBitRate.qlgenerator` in `~/Library/QuickLook` (you may have to create the directory first).

I just tested it and got name, artist, album and time shown for a few mp3:s of mine on osx Yosemite (10.10.2). It might be missing the album artwork, but I haven't taken the time to dig up a file I know has that embedded.

Comment: Not working on my side... I have submitted an issue on Git Hub.

Comment: I added installation instructions above, in case those aren't familiar already.